# How can i use an else function in xslt 1.0 / xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
   <cac:InvoiceLine xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
  <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">4</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:InvoicedQuantity xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" unitCode="KWH">10825.00000000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  <cbc:LineExtensionAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">405.94</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
  <cac:InvoicePeriod>
     <cbc:StartDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-01-01</cbc:StartDate>
     <cbc:EndDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-01-08</cbc:EndDate>
  </cac:InvoicePeriod>
  <cac:Item>
     <cbc:Description xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Opslag duurzame energie (schijf 2)</cbc:Description>
     <cbc:Name xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Opslag duurzame energie (schijf 2)</cbc:Name>
     <cac:CommodityClassification>
        <cbc:ItemClassificationcode xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" listID="ZZZ">83101800</cbc:ItemClassificationcode>
     </cac:CommodityClassification>
     <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">21.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
           <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
     </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
  </cac:Item>
  <cac:Price>
     <cbc:PriceAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">0.0375000</cbc:PriceAmount>
  </cac:Price>
 </cac:InvoiceLine>
   <cac:InvoiceLine xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
      <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">5</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" unitCode="ANN">-0.02185792</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">-9.52</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cac:InvoicePeriod>
         <cbc:StartDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-01-01</cbc:StartDate>
         <cbc:EndDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-01-08</cbc:EndDate>
      </cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cac:Item>
         <cbc:Description xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Netbeheerkosten</cbc:Description>
         <cbc:Name xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Netbeheerkosten</cbc:Name>
         <cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cbc:ItemClassificationcode xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" listID="ZZZ">83101800</cbc:ItemClassificationcode>
         </cac:CommodityClassification>
         <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">21.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
               <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
         </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </cac:Item>
      <cac:Price>
         <cbc:PriceAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">435.6800000</cbc:PriceAmount>
      </cac:Price>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
   <cac:InvoiceLine xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
      <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">1</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" unitCode="MON">0.25810000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">0.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cac:InvoicePeriod>
         <cbc:StartDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-01-01</cbc:StartDate>
         <cbc:EndDate xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2020-02-08</cbc:EndDate>
      </cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cac:Item>
         <cbc:Description xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit</cbc:Description>
         <cbc:Name xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit</cbc:Name>
         <cac:CommodityClassification>
            <cbc:ItemClassificationcode xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" listID="ZZZ">83101800</cbc:ItemClassificationcode>
         </cac:CommodityClassification>
         <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">21.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
               <cbc:ID xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
         </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </cac:Item>
      <cac:Price>
         <cbc:PriceAmount xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" currencyID="EUR">0.0000000</cbc:PriceAmount>
      </cac:Price>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
</ubl:Invoice>
```

Above you can find an piece of the XML i got. I want the following: if ItemClassificationCode is 83101800 and Item/Description is "Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit" then "Elektra1" Elseif ItemClassificationCode is 83101800 and Item/Description is "Netbeheerkosten" Then "Net1" Elseif ItemClassificationCode is 83101800 then "Elektra" Else ""

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='InvoiceLine']">
      <xsl:if test="*[local-name()='Item']/*[local-name()='CommodityClassification']/*[local-name()='ItemClassificationcode']='83101800'">Elektra</xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="*[local-name()='Item']/*[local-name()='CommodityClassification']/*[local-name()='ItemClassificationcode']='83101800' and *[local-name()='Item']/*[local-name()='Description']='Netbeheerkosten'">Net1</xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="*[local-name()='Item']/*[local-name()='CommodityClassification']/*[local-name()='ItemClassificationcode']='83101800' and *[local-name()='Item']/*[local-name()='Description']='Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit'">Elektra1</xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However the code above just gets me the results from everything. So ElektraNet1Elektra1 but I just want Net1 or Elektra 1 if the InvoiceLine has both of the variables depending on it. So if the itemcode is 83101800 AND the description says Netbeheerkosten then it should be Net1 and Net1 only..

Can someone please help me? I tried it also with xsl:otherwhise when etc.. but I don't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Use [xsl:choose](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose). -- P.S. Use prefixes instead of the `*[local-name()='...']` hack.

Comment: Could you please help me with that one? I'm pretty new to xsl (+/- 1 year).

Comment: No, because your XML is incomplete and you haven't shown the expected result. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Expected result should be (in this case): Elektra (line 1) Net1 (line 2) and Elektra1  (line 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/ubl:Invoice">
    <xsl:for-each select="cac:InvoiceLine[cac:Item/cac:CommodityClassification/cbc:ItemClassificationcode='83101800']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="cac:Item/cbc:Description='Netbeheerkosten'">Net1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="cac:Item/cbc:Description='Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit'">Elektra1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Elektra</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This requires your stylesheet to contain the namespace declarations used in the source XML.

Comment: Thank you!! this did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what template rules are for:

```
<xsl:template match="/ubl:Invoice">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cac:InvoiceLine[cac:Item/cac:CommodityClassification/cbc:ItemClassificationcode='83101800']">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cac:Item[cbc:Description='Netbeheerkosten']">Net1</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cac:Item[cbc:Description='Termijnbedrag Elektriciteit']">Net1</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cac:Item">Elektra</xsl:template>
```